# How to create webchat application in VB.net using ChatJs

Tags: vb.net, chatjs

Hello everyone I am working on dating website.in my website I want to implement chatting functionality.And I am using VB.net.I refer [this](https://www.junnark.com/blog/detail/build-a-web-chat-application-using-asp-net-3-5-linq-and-ajax-in-c-sharp) 
tutorial from this tutorial I am able to implement group chat
But I want one to one chatting how can I do that.

Any suggestions or help will be appreciated..
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same chat window used in the article and modify the source code as per your requirement.

You can give the list of online users at right hand side and after clicking on particular user it will open that chat window & here retrieve only details of that particular user instead of all the users.

If you are okay with Linq then use the same code as it by adding new dbml. or you can go with your data retrieval way of database. The logic is clearly mentioned in that article you just need to remove or/and modify code as per your requirement.

Comment: .Thanks.But the problem is I want to implement in VB.Net.I tried google but have not get any article using VB.Net.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't used VB.Net. But I think you can achieve this by using the same alternative code in VB.NET. For VB syntax you have do it by yourself. I think the logic is clear to you now just need to implement in VB.Net. Hope it helps. Best Luck (y)